# Последовательность выполнения операций

Tags: java, swing, таймер

Пытаюсь разобраться с использованием классов swing.
Возник такой вопрос:

предположим в начале программы я создаю объект swing Timer и запускаю его

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer(1000,this);
myTimer.start();
```

Далее программа продолжается, выполняются какие-нибудь расчёты, вычисления и т.д.
Но проходит 1000 мсек и myTimer вызывает метод actionPerformed().
Хочу понять в какой последовательности будут выполнятся операции.
Может быть основная программа остановится и будет ожидать пока не закончится выполнение метода actionPerformed()?
А может быть какой другой вариант?
Кто в курсе подскажите, как на самом деле будут выполняться операции?

Comment: Не работал с этим таймером по этому ничего сказать не могу, но почему бы вам самим не поставить breakpoint и не продебажить поведение программы в отладчике?

Comment: Честно говоря не знаю, как использовать отладчик вместе с таймером. Таймер будет вызывать метод каждые 50 мсек. Если я буду в режиме отладки, то  практически не выйду из метода обработки таймера?!

Comment: Поставьте задержку в 5 минут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы объяснить как работает таймер рассмотрим, как в общем работает `swing`, а точнее AWT, на котором `swing` основывается.

AWT запускает специальный фоновый поток (thread), задачей которого является обработка событий в приложении. Условно, этот поток работает так:

```
while (true) {
   while (eventQueue.isEmpty()) {
      sleep(1);
   }
   processEvent(eventQueue.getNext());
}
```

Т.е. этот поток в цикле достает события из очереди и обрабатывает их доставляя соответствующим обработчикам (классам реализующим `ActionListener`). В очередь же события добавляются после действия пользователя (нажатие на кнопку или ввод в текстовое поле), программно - используя механизмы типа [invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) или по событию от таймера.

Важный момент, что этот поток выполнения, не тот же, в котором выполняется метод main, а специально предназначенный для обработки событий. Т.е. главный поток приложения может делать какие-то действия , а при этом поток обработки событий будет работать параллельно. Конечно, они могут взаимодействовать, и в этом случае нужна синхронизация, как и при любом использовании многопоточности.

Теперь собственно о таймере.

`Timer` из swing работает совместно з общим механизмом обработки событий. То есть когда приходит время срабатывать таймеру, то событие срабатывания таймера добавляется в очередь событий. События из очереди обрабатываются как и другие события типа нажатия на кнопку и т.п., т.е. в основном потоке обработки событий.

Из этого следует, что `actionPerformed` не вызовется моментально, если в этот момент обрабатывается другое событие. Это произойдет после того, как все события случившиеся до срабатывания таймера, будут обработаны. Если при этом основной поток выполняет что-то, обработчик таймера будет выполнен параллельно с действиями в главном потоке.

Comment: Добавил немного информации о том, как в общих чертах работает `swing`.

Comment: Теперь всё понятно, спасибо